# Chunk code for coxph for specific values to publish as a text in markdown

Tags: r, text, output, r-markdown, cox-regression

What is chunk code for *coxph* formula, as I want to extract coefficient `(exp(coef) and p value)` as a text for markdown text for future knit to HTML?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to obtain the coefficient and p-value is using the `tidy` function in the `broom` package. As you did not provid an example, I used the example shown in the `coxph` Rdocumentation page.

```
library(broom)
library(survival)

# Taken from the coxph function documentation example
test1 <- list(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3), 
              status=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0), 
              x=c(0,2,1,1,1,0,0), 
              sex=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1)) 

# Fit a stratified model 
resul <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), test1) 

# Use tidy to convert result into a tibble
resul_df <- tidy(resul)

# Call the desired element by column name
# Exponent of coefficient
exp(resul_df$estimate)
# P value
resul_df$p.value
```